# push local notification every 2 day (or 3 day, 4 day...) at 20:00:00 pm for flutter

Tags: flutter

im using flutter_local_notifications for my app. But, it only suport push notify every day for at the moment. How to make it push notify every 2 day (or some day) at the moment ( example 20h PM...). Thank for support.

Answer (score 0):

Use workmanager package to send push notifications periodically like the below:

```
void startRemainderTasks() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final isAlarmSet = prefs.getString('isAlarmSet') ?? 'false';
  if (!convertStringToBool(isAlarmSet)) {
    prefs.setString('isAlarmSet', 'true');
    await Workmanager().initialize(
      callbackDispatcher,
      // isInDebugMode: true,
    );
    await Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask(
      "periodicTask",
      "appRemainder",
      initialDelay: const Duration(days: 2),
      frequency: const Duration(days: 2),
    );
  }
}
```

Use the initialDelay and frequency parameters to set the notification as periodically. The above notification will be sent every two days.

Don't forget to cancel the workmanager when the app is logged out or whenever you want.

```
 Workmanager().cancelAll();
```

for more details, refer
[workmanager: ^0.5.2](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager)

Comment: thank you, but i want sen notify every two day at 20:00:00 PM. your code only send every two day